# getting Monday date from given week and year using java.time package

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-time

I want to get Monday date from given week and year using Java 8 package java.time. 
But at some point I am facing issue as it's not returning proper date.

```
private LocalDate getDateFromWeekAndYear(final String week,final String year){
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    date = date.with(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 1);
    date = date.with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), Long.parseLong(week));
    date = date.with(WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear(), Long.parseLong(year));

    return date;
}
```

For example:

- If I pass week=1 and year=2013 then date is : 2012-12-31.
- But if I pass week=53 and year=2015 then date is : 2014-12-29. I expected 2014-12-28.

Is there any logical mistake I am making or some other issue ?

Comment: you mean getting current date using YearMonth.of(int year, int month) ?

Comment: 29/12/2014 was a Monday - why do you expect 28/12/2014? Also note that it would be clearer to use `DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getValue()` instead of `1`.

Comment: You don't need any information of the current date, no need to start with that. You can set the week and year with `YearMonth.of(int year, int month)`, then set the day of the week

Comment: I guess it's converting 53rd week of 2015 to 1st week of 2015 as in 2015 only 52 weeks are there. Solved the issue

Comment: @AbhinayPandey What is your definition of week number? I can think of at least four definitions. Did you intend the [ISO 8601 standard definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)?

Comment: @AbhinayPandey No your issue is still not solved. You have applied the wrong order of manipulations in your helper method, see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is astonishingly more difficult than the partially invalid expectations of OP and most answers show.

**First to say: It is very important to define the correct order of week-based-manipulations.** The OP has first applied day-manipulation, then year-based manipulation. The correct approach is in reverse! I will show the right helper method implementation:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(
      getDateFromWeekAndYear("53", "2015")); // 2015-12-28, NOT 2014-12-28
    System.out.println(
      getDateFromWeekAndYear("53", "2015").get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear())); // 53
    System.out.println(
      getDateFromWeekAndYear("53", "2014")); // 2014-12-29
    System.out.println(
      getDateFromWeekAndYear("53", "2014").get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear())); // 1
}

private static LocalDate getDateFromWeekAndYear(final String week,final String year) {
    int y = Integer.parseInt(year);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(y, 7, 1); // safer than choosing current date
    // date = date.with(WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear(), y); // no longer necessary
    date = date.with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), Long.parseLong(week));
    date = date.with(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 1);

    return date;
}
```

If you don't respect this specific order then you will indeed get sometimes a 2014-date for the input 2015-W53 (depending on the current date).

Second problem: **I have also avoided to start with current date in order to be not near start or end of calendar year** (calendar year != week-based-year) and instead chosen midth of year as starting point.

**The third problem is lenient handling of week 53 in (week-based)-year 2014.** It does not exist because 2014 had only 52 weeks!!! A strict algorithm should recognize and reject such an input. Therefore I advise against using `YearWeek.of(2014, 53)` (in the external library Threeten-Extra) resulting in the first week of 2015, see also its [javadoc](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html#of-int-int-). Better than such lenient handling would have been

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.of(2014, 52);
if (yw.is53WeekYear()) {
  yw = YearWeek.of(2014, 53);
}
```

or using this code from my own time library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) (whose class [CalendarWeek](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/CalendarWeek.html) has extra i18n-features and extra week arithmetic in comparison with `YearWeek`):

```
CalendarWeek.of(2014, 53); // throws an exception
System.out.println(CalendarWeek.of(2014, 1).withLastWeekOfYear()); // 2014-W52
```

**Only using `java.time`-package:**

Using such external libraries would at least have helped to solve the first problem in a transparent way. If you are not willing to add an extra dependency then you can do this to handle week 53 if invalid:

If the expression `WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear()` applied on the result of your helper method yields the value 1 then you know that week 53 was invalid. And then you can decide if you want to accept lenient handling or to throw an exception. But silent adjusting such an invalid input is IMHO bad design.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It really cleared my doubt. I was applying wrong order to fetch date.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to calculate the first Monday of the first week of the year,
then simply plus multi of 7 to the date.

```
public static LocalDate firstMonday(int week, int year) {

    LocalDate firstMonOfFirstWeek = LocalDate.now()
            .with(IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR, year) // year
            .with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 1) // First week of the year
            .with(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1); // Monday

    // Plus multi of 7
    return firstMonOfFirstWeek.plusDays( (week - 1) * 7);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(firstMonday(1, 2013)); // 2012-12-31
    System.out.println(firstMonday(53 ,2015 )); // 2015-12-28
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
YearWeek.of ( 2013 , 1 ).atDay ( DayOfWeek.MONDAY )
```

## Incorrect expectations

Your expectations are not correct. The Monday of `2015-W53` is `2015-12-28`, not `2014-12-28`, year 2015 rather than 2014. There is no reason to expect 2014. Please edit your Question to explain your thoughts, if you need more explanation.

You may be confused about a calendar-year versus a week-based year. In the [ISO 8601 definition of a week based year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), **week number one contains the first Thursday of the calendar-year**. This means we have some overlap between the years. The last few days of a calendar-year may reside in the following week-based-year. And vice-versa, the first few days of a calendar-year may reside in the previous week-based-year.

As an example, you can see in the screenshot below, the last day of calendar 2012 (December 31) falls in week one of the following week-based-year of 2013 at week number 1. And in the other screen shot, we have the opposite, where the first three days of calendar 2016 (January 1, 2, & 3) land in the week-based-year of 2015 at week number 53.

- The Monday of `2013-W01` is `2012-12-31`.
- The Monday of `2015-W53` is `2015-12-28`.

[image: 2013-W01 calendar screen shot]

[image: 2015-W53 calendar screen shot]

## `YearWeek`

I suggest adding the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to make use of of the [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class. Rather than pass around mere integer numbers for year and week, pass around objects of this class. Doing so makes your code more self-documenting, provides type-safety, and ensures valid values.

```
// Pass ( week-based-year-number, week-number ). *Not* calendar year! See the ISO 8601 standard.
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.of( 2013 , 1 );
```

You can pull any day from that week.

```
LocalDate ld = yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY );
```

Let's try this kind of code.

```
YearWeek yw1 = YearWeek.of ( 2013 , 1 );
LocalDate ld1 = yw1.atDay ( DayOfWeek.MONDAY );

YearWeek yw2 = YearWeek.of ( 2015 , 53 );
LocalDate ld2 = yw2.atDay ( DayOfWeek.MONDAY );

System.out.println ( "yw1: " + yw1 + " Monday: " + ld1 );
System.out.println ( "yw2: " + yw2 + " Monday: " + ld2 );
```

> yw1: 2013-W01 Monday: 2012-12-31
>
> yw2: 2015-W53 Monday: 2015-12-28

---

Tip: To see those [ISO 8601 standard week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) numbers on a Mac in Calendar.app, set `System Preferences` > `Language & Region` > `Calendar` > `ISO 8601`. Then in Calendar.app, set `Preferences` > `Advanced` > `Show week numbers`.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I simply misread "2014" in the Question as "2015", while focusing on the matching month 12 and day 28. I fixed my Answer, reversing my statement about "correct expectations". Thanks for the critique.

Comment: Now retracting my downvote. I agree with you that using an external lib with special class for a combination of week-based year and week-of-year can reduce the headache of making such a helper method like the OP had done.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted Monday of a week about 6 month ago - to be specific 26 weeks ago.. below code gave me the required date:

```
LocalDate.now().minusWeeks(26).with(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getValue())
```